# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select' in web application

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL. I used FlySpeed SQL builder to write this query and it works there but when I use this code in web application I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Basically, I want to write this: If count is below 20 it returns nothing, if it is over 20 it triggers notification system.

```
Select
  sr.status,
  sr.assetsiteid
From
  sr
Where
  sr.status = 'pending' And
  sr.assetsiteid = 'gp'
Group By
  sr.status, sr.assetsiteid
Having
  count(*) > 20
Order By
  count(*) Desc
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using this in a web application? Your sql looks fine

Comment: Please get in the habbit of using semicolons `;` at the end of each query.

Comment: so, mysql or sql server?. Is there more code?

Comment: I suspect FlySpeed, whatever that is, is adding some statement(s) before the query. You can always add a semi-colon to the *beginning* of the query.

Comment: Is "sr" the name of a table in your database?

Comment: This is all the code. As far as I know it is SQL. The application is called IBM Maximo and yes, SR is the table.